# Find/Rename large file in Linux

Tags: linux, file, size

I am learning how to use Linux command in terminal and find/rename large file. As a first try

```
find . -type f +size 1G
```

gives this message

> find: paths must precede expression: +size Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P]
>   [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...]
>   [expression]

What is the best way to

1. Find/ rename large file
2. Move them to a specific folder

Thanks in advance, Karlo

Comment: Did you consider reading the documentation (RTFM) of [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)? It would have been quicker than asking here!

Answer (score 3):

Find all files larger than 1G:

find . -type f -size +1G

You can execute a command on the selected files by adding '-exec' option. For examples:

Echo the file name (result similar to -print):
find . -type f -size +1G -exec echo '{}' \;

Add a suffix _Ren to the file:
find . -type f -size +1G -exec mv '{}' '{}_Ren' \;

Move file to temp folder:
find . -type f -size +1G -exec mv '{}' /tmp \;

Comment: Without wishing to be picky, this either renames the file in-situ or moves it into /tmp but with the entire directory name attached. So ./abc/def/my_large_file.avi ends up being /tmp./abc/def/my_large_file.avi

Comment: @RolfofSaxony In your example, the move becomes:
    mv ./abc/def/my_large_file.avi /tmp
file my_large_file.avi is copied to /tmp, so the end result is /tmp/my_arge_file.avi.

The rename command to add _Ren is meant to change the file name without moving it to another location.

Comment: @HarveyPham My point was that one usually wishes to move the file to another place without including all the baggage of the directories and subdirectories as well and the question was find, rename and move the file to a specific directory. It's semantics I suppose, I did try to get your solution to do that but couldn't find a way. If I had, I would have up voted your solution myself.

Comment: @HarveyPham ps as it is the OP has swanned off into the ether and accepted neither answer, such is life!

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, I'm sorry that I was not clear on previous post. I understand your point about not including all the subdirectories. However, mv command execute in the manner that I suggested does not create subdirectories. "mv ./abc/def/my_large_file.avi /tmp" meant move file my_large_file.avi at location ./abc/def to /tmp. So when you execute that command you get /tmp/my_large_file.avi, not /tmp/abc/def/my_large_file.avi. You can run find twice, first to rename the file in the original location, then move them to specific folder.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, use:

```
find /home/* -size +1G -print
```

and see if that gets you closer to what you are after.

Edit:
The following should do what you want and handles spaces in directory and file names.

```
#!/bin/bash
# $1 is path to search, $2 greater than size in Gb to search for, $3 destination
IFS=$'\n'
for x in `find $1 -size +$2G -print`
        do
                y=`basename "$x"`
                echo "$x" "being copied to " $3/copy_"$y"
                mv "$x" $3/copy_"$y"
        done
```

Note that the text `copy_` could be amended to whatever you want to use for renaming the file or you could make that the 4th parameter on the command line and change the code to read `$3/$4"$y"`

Place the code (from the line #!/bin/bash to the end) into a file, lets call it bigfind.sh
then chmod +x bigfind.sh
This will allow you to execute the script
Let us assume that you want to look for large files in /home/karlo, they should be bigger than 1Gb and you want to move them to /home/public
Your command (assuming that you are currently in /home/karlo and your script bigfind.sh is also in that directory) would be:
./bigfind.sh ./ 1 /home/public
or
./bigfind.sh /home/karlo 1 /home/public
I you were in the root directory (/) for example, the command would be:
/home/karlo/bigfind.sh /home/karlo 1 /home/public

I suspect that you may already know a lot of this but I hope it helps.

Comment: Dear Rolf, For me as a beginner, it was a little hard to comprehend you  script.  Now, I can appreciate your solution for my problem.  Many many thanks for your help

Comment: @KarloGonzales In that case, perhaps I should have added a few explanatory notes. I will edit the answer appropriately